# How do I pop the item underneath the top item in a stack?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, methods

I am trying to get the value below the top value in a stack and return it using pop(). Does anyone know how I could do this?

Here's what I have so far...(not much I'm afraid)

```
template <typename T> //Pop second from the top method
void programStack<T>::popSecondFromTop() {

}
```

Comment: You don't. That's the point of a stack. Best you can do is record the top, pop the stack, pop the stack, push the stored value back on. If you find yourself having to do this, stack probably isn't the right data structure for the job.

Comment: That said, it feels like you may be struggling with [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . If you outline the problem you are trying to solve that lead you to needing this functionality, someone may be able to suggest a better solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: You can simply store the value, pop the top, store the second value, pop again, push the first value to the stack, then return

Comment: What is the header for `programStack`? That would help us answer you.

Answer (score 0):

As the others states, the purpose of stack is to be able get last inserted element to stack. Last in first out (LIFO) principle applies for it. But if you really want to pop out the second element, first you should save the top one, then pop it. After it you can get your element and pop it. At last step, you should insert the first element. Thats all.